# unsource a file in a script

Tags: bash, sorting

we have a script that sources in a bunch of utilities including a custom sort function in a script called function.sh. Later in my parent script I want to use the bash sort. Is there anyway to unsource or dereference the custom sort? I can't rename the custom sort function because it is used in so many other scripts.

Comment: You can't "unsource" a script, because sourcing a script simply executes the commands normally. There's nothing that remembers what was done by each script. But you can delete a function, see the linked question.

Comment: If the script you sourced did `cat filename`, how would you undo that?

Comment: `command source` will invoke the external (non-function) `source` command.